# How can I predict the winning position for player X or O in a tic tac toe game and tell the user the position?

Tags: c

so I wrote a function that allows the user to find if any next move or next play for any player X or O who has the turn to play is winning move. The function will print the cell number or ID that if the player places an X or O in it he/she will win the game. If there is more than one cell where the player could place his symbol in and win the game the function should print all the winning cells for that player.

```
I made a simple implementation of the code but it seems to work but not print right position. Any help would be great. Thanks.

void ListWinningCells(int m, int n, char board[][n])
{
    int check = IsValidBoard(m, n, board);
    if(check == 1){
        // for row:
        if((board[0][0] == 'X' || board[0][0] == 'O') && (board[0][2] == 'X' || board[0][2] == 'O')){
            printf("Winning cell is 2 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }
        if((board[1][0] == 'X' || board[1][0] == 'O') && (board[1][2] == 'X' || board[1][2] == 'O')){
           printf("Winning cell is 5 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }
        if((board[2][0] == 'X' || board[2][0] == 'O') && (board[2][2] == 'X' || board[2][2] == 'O')){
            printf("Winning cell is 8 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }

        // for column
        if((board[0][0] == 'X' || board[0][0] == 'O') && (board[2][0] == 'X' || board[2][0] == 'O')){
            printf("Winning cell is 4 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }
        if((board[0][1] == 'X' || board[0][1] == 'O') && (board[2][1] == 'X' || board[2][1] == 'O')){
            printf("Winning cell is 5 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }
        if((board[0][2] == 'X' || board[0][2] == 'O') && (board[2][2] == 'X' || board[2][2] == 'O')){
            printf("Winning cell is 6 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }

        // for diagonal
        if((board[0][0] == 'X' || board[0][0] == 'O') && (board[2][2] == 'X' || board[2][2] == 'O')){
            printf("Winning cell is 5 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }
        if((board[0][2] == 'X' || board[0][2] == 'O') && (board[2][0] == 'X' || board[2][0] == 'O')){
            printf("Winning cell is 5 for player %c\n", board[0][0]);
        }
    }
    else{
       IsValidBoard(m, n, board); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `I made a simple implementation of the code but it seems to work but not print right position.` what does it mean?

Comment: When it isn't a valid board, you're checking whether it's a valid board. I don't think it's your problem, but it seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at your first if statement:

```
if((board[0][0] == 'X' || board[0][0] == 'O') && (board[0][2] == 'X' || board[0][2] == 'O'))
```

If 'X' is on board[0][0] and 'O' is on board[0][2] the statement would be true, but that isn't correct. It should be:

```
if((board[0][0] == 'X' || board[0][0] == 'O') && (board[0][2] == board[0][0]))
```

So it would return that the winning cell is 2. You should also consider that some cases are not being taken into account, as cell 1 and cell 3 being the winning cell, I do not know if it is the intention.

You should also consider using for loops to check the positions.